# Testing DOM using a combination of Jasmine, JQuery Mobile and an Async AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, asynchronous, jasmine

I'm currently working on a mobile application which i decided to realize using JQuery Mobile. However, since it'll be an official app it requires me to test it and I decided to go with Jasmine which I learned to deal with at school.

Currently I have both a client and server side which communicates using AJAX (`$.getJSON`) requests.

When one of these AJAX requests gets forwarded to its `callback` method it'll call an `Notification` class to implement a `div` with the notification inside of it.

My problem at the moment is that it always seemed to be working when I was using the following code:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    var expectedResult = "error";
    var result = $("#test .ui-content .contentContainer .notification").text();
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
}, 4000);
```

However, after a few days I started on a new module, and edited these values it kept working which would be incredibly wrong since its old - non existing - code.

So I noticed this unit test never actually worked.

So I started looking for alternative methods and found the `runs` and `waitsFor` functions, but I cant seem to get them working.

So here is a test:

```
it('should display an error when trying to add a new contact', function () {
    runs(function () {
        var contact = new Contact();
        contact.addContact();
    });

    waitsFor(function () {
        expect($("#test .ui-content .contentContainer .notification")).toBeVisible();
    }, 5000);

    var expectedResult = "asdf";
    var result = $("#test .ui-content .contentContainer .notification").text();
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
});
```

callback method:

```
this.addContact_callback = function (data) {
    $('#createContactForm')[0].reset();
    $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        (new Contact()).retrieveContactList();
        (new NotificationBox()).show(data.message[0], data.message[1]);
    }, 250)
};
```

And my notification:

```
function NotificationBox() {
    this.show = function (message, type) {
        var activePage = $("body .ui-page-active").attr("id");
        var create = "<div class='notification " + type + "'>" + message + "</div>";
        $("#" + activePage + " .ui-content .contentContainer .notification").remove();
        $("#" + activePage + " .ui-content .contentContainer").prepend(
            $(create).hide().fadeIn('slow').delay(2500).fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $(this).remove();
            })
        );
    };
}
```

I hope someone will be able to provide me a solution to this major problem.

Yours Sincerely,
Larssy1

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the `waitsFor` method. If you read the [official documentation](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs#waitsforfunction-optional-message-optional-timeout), `waitsFor` needs to return a value that indicates if the wait time is over or not.

What you probably want to do is the following :

```
waitsFor(function () {
    return $("#test .ui-content .contentContainer .notification").is(":visible");
}, 5000);
```

You are also missing a run block for the last section of your test.

```
runs(function () {
    var expectedResult = "asdf";
    var result = $("#test .ui-content .contentContainer .notification").text();
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
});
```

Comment: Both methods are there, check the second code snippet. Since I had no answer I'm currently refactoring my code which allows me not to check by DOM but by a returned value.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not be seen as a solution, it does create better managable and testable code.

In my given code examples I was forwarding the code to external callback methods, as in the given code I used `addContact_callback`. The only way to track the actual result was determing what the text of the `notification` element class was.

Having this said, it is pretty clear that if you face this problem, you might have written dirty code.

For that reason I changed my code to something better, it uses an internal callback method. Which means the code would look like something like this:

```
function handleSomething () {
    this.retrieveSomething(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}

function retrieveSomething (callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "127.0.0.1/my.php",
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            return callback($.parseJSON(data);
        }
    });
}
```

This makes sure my code is way easier to test since I can implement a custom callback function for unit tests.

Remember the old Unit Test? well this went from:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    var expectedResult = "error";
    var result = $("#test .ui-content .contentContainer .notification").text();
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
}, 4000);
```

to :

```
var contact = new Contact();
contact.retrieveSomething(function (data) {
    var expectedResult = (new Contact()).errorMessages[4];
    expect(data.message).toBe(expectedResult);
});
```

Conslusion: Make sure you can always test your return output instead of simply moving it to the UI and then trying to test whether the result is the same as you would expect.